# Self-decided tag burnination?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

[Certain user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277291/priyank) is currently flooding the edit review queue trying to change all [multi-device-hybrid-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-device-hybrid-apps) tagged questions into a new tag he recently created: [visual-studio-cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-cordova) and of course robo-reviewers are happily approving these edits.

Shouldn't there be an official thread on Meta about such conversions before any action like this is taken?

Comment: Those tags should be synonyms of each other or is it just a rename?

Comment: Don't think there should be an "official thread" for every little action unless it's questionable (or not "little" at all and thus *very likely questionable* which this falls under, I surmise). Now, it turns out, it is, and **this** is the official thread!

Comment: rene - I read up on synonyms. Unfortunately I don't have enough points (2500) to upvote the suggestion that has already been started. What do you advise?

Comment: So the tags should be synonyms? @Priyank

Comment: Yep, they are synonyms. The product was recently renamed. Can the mods help me approve the synonym?

Comment: I think that is better than you retagging all those questions...

Comment: Waiting for a mod to suggest if I should continue retagging or if someone can help approving the synonym? there's not that many left tbh

Comment: @Priyank Please don't mass-retag thru suggested edits. If you want to help with a retagging, first propose it on meta, and if you want to suggest edits, make them substantial by fixing multiple problems in the post.

Comment: @Priyank definitely discuss it with a Q on meta and if the community agrees moderators will help as needed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there should be a request here on Meta instead of a mass retag through suggested edits. Moderators can just make these tags synonyms if that's warranted.